# Using gimbal_2d Camera in ArduPilot Gazebo Simulator

Tags: python

I am seeking assistance with a problem regarding the control of the gimbal_2d camera in the ArduPilot Gazebo simulator.
have a gimbal_2d camera, and there is a topic “/tilt_cmd” in the simulator (gazebo topic -t “/tilt_cmd”), but it is not visible in ROS. I aim to configure camera control through ROS, but I am encountering the issue of the topic not being visible in ROS.

I seek advice and assistance on the following questions:

How can I make the “/tilt_cmd” topic visible in ROS?
What is the correct procedure for configuring control of the gimbal_2d camera through ROS on the drone?
Additionally, I am interested in enabling zoom functionality for the camera. Could you please provide guidance on achieving this?

I would appreciate any support and recommendations. Thank you!

My setup details are as follows:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
ROS: Noetic
ArduPilot Gazebo version https://github.com/Intelligent-Quads/iq_tutorials/blob/master/docs/installing_gazebo_arduplugin.md